# Required Help in integrating Google Meet and Calendrer Service in Dot Net Core API Applications

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-meet

We want to integrate the google meet and calendar service in our .NET Core API, where in the background the meeting link will generate and it will send to respective email ids. We are happy to purchase if any service is paid